# Remove last two characters from column names of all the columns in Dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am joining the two dataframes (a,b) with identical columns / column names using the user ID key and while joining, I had to give suffix characters, in order for it to get created. The following is the command I used,

```
a.join(b,how='inner', on='userId',lsuffix="_1")
```

If I dont use this suffix, I am getting error. But I dont want the column names to change because, that is causing a problem while running other analysis. So I want to remove this "_1" character from all the column names of the resulting dataframe. Can anybody suggest me an efficient way to remove last two characters of names of all the columns in the Pandas dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just rename the columns?

Comment: @JoeR I have about 76 columns and 50 such dataframes. So Doing in manually is not a solution!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This snippet should get the job done :

```
df.columns = pd.Index(map(lambda x : str(x)[:-2], df.columns))
```

Edit : This is a better way to do it

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x : str(x)[:-2])
```

In both cases, all we're doing is iterating through the columns and apply some function.  In this case, the function converts something into a string and takes everything up until the last two characters.

I'm sure there are a few other ways you could do this.

Comment: As @Alexander pointed out, you do need to have unique column names for this to work.   If all non-join keys were unique to begin with, you should just exclude the suffix.  If you're getting an error that's because you have overlapping names and the concept of "join" is not defined.  You may want to post up some sample data, because it sounds like there you're encountering some other issues causing confusion (such as how or when to use a join).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) like so

```
In [214]: import functools as ft

In [215]: f = ft.partial(np.random.choice, *[5, 3])

In [225]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': f(), 'b': f(), 'c': f(), 'a_1': f(), 'b_1': f(), 'c_1': f()})

In [226]: df
Out[226]:
   a  b  c  a_1  b_1  c_1
0  4  2  0    2    3    2
1  0  0  3    2    1    1
2  4  0  4    4    4    3

In [227]: df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_1')

In [228]: df
Out[228]:
   a  b  c  a  b  c
0  4  2  0  2  3  2
1  0  0  3  2  1  1
2  4  0  4  4  4  3
```

However if you need something more flexible (albeit probably a bit slower), you can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) which, with the power of regexes, will allow you to select which part of the column name you would like to keep

```
In [216]: df = pd.DataFrame({f'{c}_{i}': f() for i in range(3) for c in 'abc'})

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
   a_0  b_0  c_0  a_1  b_1  c_1  a_2  b_2  c_2
0    0    1    0    2    2    4    0    0    3
1    0    0    3    1    4    2    4    3    2
2    2    0    1    0    0    2    2    2    1

In [223]: df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'(.*)_\d+')[0]

In [224]: df
Out[224]:
0  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  1  0  0  0  2  1  1  2
1  1  0  1  0  1  2  0  4  1
2  1  3  1  3  4  2  0  1  1
```

Idea to use `df.columns.str` came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097451/5491375) answer