# How to flatten/concatenate multiple columns with similar information based on one index column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about flattening or collapsing a dataframe from several columns in one row with information about a key to several rows each with the same key column and the appropriate data. Suppose a dataframe is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
              'START_1': ['1990-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2005-01-01'],
              'END_1': ['1990-02-14', '2000-03-01', '2005-12-31'],
              'MEANING_1': ['SOMETHING', 'OR', 'OTHER'],
              'START_2': ['1990-02-15', None, '2006-01-01'],
              'END_2': ['1990-06-14', None, '2006-12-31'],
              'MEANING_2': ['ELSE', None, 'ANOTHER']})
  CODE     START_1       END_1  MEANING_1     START_2       END_2 MEANING_2
0   AA  1990-01-01  1990-02-14  SOMETHING  1990-02-15  1990-06-14      ELSE
1   BB  2000-01-01  2000-03-01         OR        None        None      None
2   CC  2005-01-01  2005-12-31      OTHER  2006-01-01  2006-12-31   ANOTHER
```

and I need to get it into a form somewhat like this:

```
  CODE       START         END    MEANING
0   AA  1990-01-01  1990-02-14  SOMETHING
1   AA  1990-02-15  1990-06-14       ELSE
2   BB  2000-01-01  2000-03-01         OR
3   CC  2005-01-01  2005-12-31      OTHER
4   CC  2006-01-01  2006-12-31    ANOTHER
```

I have a solution as follows:

```
df_a = df[['CODE', 'START_1', 'END_1', 'MEANING_1']]
df_b = df[['CODE', 'START_2', 'END_2', 'MEANING_2']]
df_a = df_a.rename(index=str, columns={'CODE': 'CODE',
                                'START_1': 'START',
                                'END_1': 'END',
                                'MEANING_1': 'MEANING'})
df_b = df_b.rename(index=str, columns={'CODE': 'CODE',
                                'START_2': 'START',
                                'END_2': 'END',
                                'MEANING_2': 'MEANING'})
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Which yields the desired result. Of course this doesn't seem very pythonic and  is clearly not ideal if you have more than 2 column groups which need to be collapsed (I actually have 6 in my real code). I've examined the `groupby()`, `melt()` and `stack()` methods but haven't really found them to be very useful yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There are actually some convenience functions for this called lreshape and wide_to_long but neither of them is well supported. lreshape is still "experimental" and wide_to_long has horrible argument names and has very specific input requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['END', 'MEANING', 'START'],
                i='CODE', j='Number', sep='_', suffix='*')
```

Output:

```
                    END    MEANING       START
CODE Number                                   
AA   1       1990-02-14  SOMETHING  1990-01-01
BB   1       2000-03-01         OR  2000-01-01
CC   1       2005-12-31      OTHER  2005-01-01
AA   2       1990-06-14       ELSE  1990-02-15
BB   2             None       None        None
CC   2       2006-12-31    ANOTHER  2006-01-01
```

Then, we can drop Number column/index and dropna's if you wish, e.g. `df.reset_index().drop('Number', 1)`.

Comment: Upvoted, never knew this existed, i'd also add `df.reset_index().drop('Number', 1)`.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Great addition!  Thank you.  Yeah, pd.wide_to_long is great for 'simultaneous' melt situations.

Comment: This is what I was looking for in the pandas docs. It seems to use melt under the hood so I was close but couldn't get it working. Do you know how I would accomplish the same thing with melt?

Comment: @DrPiranoid adding the melt way :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is what `melt` will achieve this

```
df1=df.melt('CODE')

df1[['New','New2']]=df1.variable.str.split('_',expand=True)
df1.set_index(['CODE','New2','New']).value.unstack()
Out[492]: 
New               END    MEANING       START
CODE New2                                   
AA   1     1990-02-14  SOMETHING  1990-01-01
     2     1990-06-14       ELSE  1990-02-15
BB   1     2000-03-01         OR  2000-01-01
     2           None       None        None
CC   1     2005-12-31      OTHER  2005-01-01
     2     2006-12-31    ANOTHER  2006-01-01
```

Comment: Awesome Wen!  I forgot about this method, I've  seen MaxU use that method also. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston yep, but pd_wide to Long is the right way for this type of question , I still remember I learn it from Ted Petrou :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. This is similar to your logic, I have just optimised a little and cleaned up the code so you only have to maintain `common_cols`, `var_cols`, `data_count`.

```
common_cols = ['CODE']
var_cols = ['START', 'END', 'MEANING']
data_count = 2

dfs = {i: df[common_cols + [k+'_'+str(int(i)) for k in var_cols]].\
          rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]) for i in range(1, data_count+1)}

pd.concat(list(dfs.values()), ignore_index=True)

#   CODE       START         END    MEANING
# 0   AA  1990-01-01  1990-02-14  SOMETHING
# 1   BB  2000-01-01  2000-03-01         OR
# 2   CC  2005-01-01  2005-12-31      OTHER
# 3   AA  1990-02-15  1990-06-14       ELSE
# 4   BB        None        None       None
# 5   CC  2006-01-01  2006-12-31    ANOTHER
```

Comment: This solution worked for me! I am surprised that there wasn't a pandas method appropriate for the task. I'm also curious how I could have phrased my question differently. It's fairly obvious what I'm asking with an example but searching for solutions was very difficult without the right vocabulary.

Comment: @DrPiranoid, I actually thought your question was very well phrased. The reproducible code helps us easily test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work.

```
# the following line get rid of _x suffix 
df = df.set_index("CODE")
df.columns = pd.Index(map(lambda x : str(x)[:-2], df.columns)
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, range(len(df.columns))[i::2]] for i in range(2)])
```

The method to remove suffix is taken from [Remove last two characters from column names of all the columns in Dataframe - Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061541/remove-last-two-characters-from-column-names-of-all-the-columns-in-dataframe-p)

It should be easy to extend the method to more than 2 columns per group. Say 6 as OP had.

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, range(len(df.columns))[i::6]] for i in range(6)])
```

Comment: @jp_data_analysis modified to be more general now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df.columns = [i[0] for i in df.columns.str.split('_')]
df = df.T
cond = df.index.duplicated()
concat_df = pd.concat([df[~cond],df[cond]],axis=1).T
sort_df = concat_df.sort_values('START').iloc[:-1]
sort_df.CO = sort_df.CO.ffill()
```