# Removing Suffix From Dataframe Column Names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove a suffix from all columns in a dataframe, however I am getting error messages. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.add_suffix('_x')

def strip_right(df.columns, _x):
    if not text.endswith("_x"):
        return text
    # else
    return text[:len(df.columns)-len("_x")]
```

Error:

```
def strip_right(tmp, "_x"):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried removing the quotations.

```
def strip_right(df.columns, _x):
    if not text.endswith(_x):
        return text
    # else
    return text[:len(df.columns)-len(_x)]
```

Error:

```
def strip_right(df.columns, _x):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.str.rstrip('_x')
`

Comment: Thank you, please post as an answer, so I can give credit. Thanks.

Comment: Use `cols` as an argument instead of `df.columns` (just to show why your `def` gives a syntaxt error, the other option is the best option to solve your original problem)

Comment: @Starbucks that is fine , happy coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a more concrete example:.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.add_suffix("_x")
    
print("With Suffix")
print(df.head())
    
def strip_right(df, suffix="_x"):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip(suffix)
  
strip_right(df) 
    
print("\n\nWithout Suffix")
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
With Suffix
   A_x  B_x  C_x  D_x
0    0    7    0    2
1    5    1    8    5
2    6    2    0    1
3    6    6    5    6
4    8    6    5    8
    
    
Without Suffix
   A  B  C  D
0  0  7  0  2
1  5  1  8  5
2  6  2  0  1
3  6  6  5  6
4  8  6  5  8
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a bug in the implementation of the accepted answer. The docs for [`pandas.Series.str.rstrip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas-series-str-rstrip) reference [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), which states:

> *"The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped."*

Instead I had to use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the actual suffix from my column names. See the modified example below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.add_suffix('_x')
df['Ex_'] = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 1))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)
print ("With Suffix")
print(df1.head())

def strip_right(df, suffix='_x'):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip(suffix)

strip_right(df1) 

print ("\n\nAfter .rstrip()")
print(df1.head())

def replace_right(df, suffix='_x'):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(suffix+'$', '', regex=True)

print ("\n\nWith Suffix")
print(df.head())

replace_right(df)

print ("\n\nAfter .replace()")
print(df.head())
```

**Output:**

```
With Suffix
   A_x  B_x  C_x  D_x  Ex_
0    4    9    2    3    4
1    1    6    5    8    6
2    2    5    2    3    6
3    1    4    7    6    4
4    3    9    3    5    8


After .rstrip()
   A  B  C  D  E
0  4  9  2  3  4
1  1  6  5  8  6
2  2  5  2  3  6
3  1  4  7  6  4
4  3  9  3  5  8


After .replace()
   A  B  C  D  Ex_
0  4  9  2  3    4
1  1  6  5  8    6
2  2  5  2  3    6
3  1  4  7  6    4
4  3  9  3  5    8
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @rcodemonkey, the accepted answer is not correct. In some cases, it will remove other characters at the end of a string because `to_strip` argument of [str.rstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) method is in fact a set of characters, not a proper suffix.

Therefore, you should either use the other proposed solution ([str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method) or I would suggest using [str.removesuffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html) method (available from python 3.9 and pandas 1.4) that is the clearest and most understood from these solutions:

```py
def remove_suffix(df, suffix='_x'):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.removesuffix(suffix)
```

Full example (taking the example from the accepted answer):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.add_suffix('_x')

# With Suffix
#    A_x  B_x  C_x  D_x
# 0    5    4    7    4
# 1    9    6    4    6
# 2    1    3    2    9
# 3    3    3    1    3
# 4    0    0    6    2

remove_suffix(df) 

# Without Suffix
#    A  B  C  D
# 0  5  4  7  4
# 1  9  6  4  6
# 2  1  3  2  9
# 3  3  3  1  3
# 4  0  0  6  2
```